# Wordnik "Trying to get property of non-object" Error when trying getDefinitions

Tags: php, html, api, wordnik

I'm trying to use the Wordnik PHP API and I'm having some trouble. I tried to use the getDefinitions method but it returns an error: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 18`.

Here is the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Word" name="word1">
            <input type="submit" placeholder="Compare">
        </form>
        <?php
            require('./wordnik/Swagger.php');
            $APIKey = '342eac9900e703079b0050d5f7008eab962195189e75bfbcb';
            $client = new APIClient($APIKey, 'http://api.wordnik.com/v4');

            $word1 = $_POST['word1'];
            $wordApi = new WordApi($client);
            $word1 = $wordApi->getDefinitions($word1, null, null);
            print $word1->text;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can also have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12769983/2377164

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your notice (not really an error in the php world) does not come from the `$word1 = $wordApi->getDefinitions($word1, null, null);` but from `print $word1->text;` is it possible?

If you check the WorldApi class :

https://github.com/wordnik/wordnik-php/blob/master/wordnik/WordApi.php#L182
https://github.com/wordnik/wordnik-php/blob/master/wordnik/WordApi.php#L138

You can see that `getDefinitions(...)` return an array of `Definition` or null.

One thing is sure, you cannot get the `->text` property from `$word1` but from one of these indexes if the return is valid. Try `$word1[0]->text`

Anyway you should also handle the case where the return of `getDefinitions(...)` return an empty array or null.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to PHP so sorry for my incompetence. I'll try it later today.

Answer (score 0):

This sample code might help you:

```
apiUrl = 'http://api.wordnik.com/v4'
apiKey = 'YOURKEYHERE'
client = swagger.ApiClient(apiKey, apiUrl)
wordApi = WordApi.WordApi(client)
res = wordApi.getWord('cat')
res2 = wordApi.getDefinitions('cat')
assert res, 'null getWord result'
assert res.word == 'cat', 'word should be "cat"'
print res.word
print dir(res2[0])
print res2[0].partOfSpeech
```